# Java : Using Functional Vs OOP Paradigms

Tags: java, functional-programming, abstraction

I Have a specific behaviour which i want to abstract out in my class.

I See two ways how i can do this.

**Option 1** : The behaviour can be overridden by the conventional subclassing of 'SomeClass'.

```
Class SomeCalss{
  public Output behaviour(Input){
    //overriden behaviour
  }
}

Class SomeOtherClass extends SomeCalss{
  public Output behaviour(Input){
    //overriden behaviour
  }
}
```

**Option 2** : The behaviour can be specified by Plugging in the functional definition from outside

```
Class SomeCalss{
  public Output behaviour(Function<Input,Output> function, Input){
    //Functional paradigm
  }
}
```

No Subclassing is needed in 'Option 2'.

**Question** : (**Edit**)

- With java now fully supporting these paradigms of functional programming from java8+ onwards, has there been any shift in the conventional process to abstract out behaviours. What is the better way of abstracting out my behaviour, and why ? Incase the same is case to case dependent, what are the cases when 1 should be used over the other ?.

Comment: Before you can answer the question you're asking, you need to ask the question, which approach is better - unfortunately, even that is subjective, as context to the problem you're trying to solve will play a large part in the decision making process. You also need to consider how it might affect your decision making processes in the future.

Comment: Yes, it's very subjective and case dependent. However, note that in your example, the two options won't be equivalent : `behavior() ` will still need an `Input`-parameter to apply the function on.

Comment: The second example is basically a Strategy Pattern and doesn't depend in any way on functional programming or Java 8.  Strategy Pattern is used when the actual function is not known until run time.  Inheritance (your first option) is used when subclass X always has the same behavior and can be fixed as such ahead of time.

Comment: @daniu : Thanks, edited.

Comment: @markspace : 'Function<Input,Output>' in java can be used to pass around lambda expressions (starting from java8+). Hence i am not passing any conventional object in the second approach, but a block of code (a 'function') which can be executed from within behaviour(). This is quite different from strategy, where the first class citizens are objects, rather thn functions. Please let know if i am missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Option 2 gives you flexibility, it forces client code to specify the Function argument, which you will probably want to avoid.

Your goal is to provide clients with a simple interface (**behaviour(input)**) and hide everything you can- so that clients stay independent from your code.

Option 3 would be

```
interface Behaves { public Output behaviour(Input i); }
class Behaviour1 implements Behaves {
  public Output behaviour(Input i){ /* your implementation here*/ }
}
class FunctionBasedBehaviour implements Behaves {
  private final Function<Input,Output> f;
  public FunctionBasedBehaviour (Function<Input,Output> f) {this.f=f;}
  public Output behaviour(Input i){  return f(i); }
}
```